# change color of ui-state-highlight to red color in datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, styling

here was my code

```
var dates = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewData["ph"]));
    $('#StartDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                    return [true, 'ui-state-highlight'];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }
    });
```

i had the date 18th was outlined in yellow.
how can i change it into red solid?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this via CSS:

```
.ui-state-highlight {
  border-color: red;
}
```

An example:

```
var dtNow = new Date();

function addDays(d) {
  return d * 86400000;
}

function showMyDate(d) {
  return d.getDate() + (d.getMonth() + 1) + d.getFullYear();
}

var dates = [
  new Date(dtNow.getTime() + addDays(5)),
  new Date(dtNow.getTime() + addDays(10)),
  new Date(dtNow.getTime() + addDays(12)),
];

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var status = [];
      $.each(dates, function(key, myDate) {
        if (showMyDate(myDate) === showMyDate(date)) {
          status = [true, 'ui-state-highlight highlight-red', ''];
        } else {
          status = [true, '', ''];
        }
      });
      return status;
    }
  });
});
```

In this example, I have added two classes: `ui-state-highlight` and `highlight-red`. This way I can directly change just the ones that need to be red.

**CSS**

```
td.ui-state-highlight.highlight-red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6fapkykr/

Comment: @EmilyGermanotta glad to help. If you found it helpful, I hope you will want to mark it as the answer.